# BST: return first entry larger than the key

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am writing to write a Java method that takes a binary search tree (BST) T and a key k, and returns the first entry larger than k that would appear in an inorder traversal. If k is absent or no key larger than k is present, return null. For example, when applied to the BST in the figure below you should return 29 if k = 23; if k = 32, you should return null.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydiBv.jpg

The pseudo code is:

```
findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(BSTNode t, int key)
// go left
findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.left, key);
// visit the node
if t.nodeValue == key 
key exists, set a boolean value to true
else if t.nodeValue > key
check if this node value is the first entry larger than key
// go right
findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.right, key);
```

The code that I have written uptil now:

```
boolean found = false;
int x = 0;
public Integer findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(BSTNode t, int key) { 
    // the scan terminates on an empty subtree
    if (t != null) {


        // descend left 
        findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.left, key); 
        // visit the node
        if (t.nodeValue == key){
            found = true;
        }

        else if (t.nodeValue > key && found == true && ? && ?){
        x = t.nodeValue;

        }
        // descend right
        findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.right, key);
        return x;
    } 

    return null;
}
```

I need help regarding the conditions that I have to use.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Guy He probably wants what condition should be used in place of the '?'s

Comment: @TechSpellBound If that what the OP wants he/she need to say it.

Comment: @Guy agreed to that!

Comment: Sry guys, I need help with condition.

Answer (score 0):

Do an in order traversal , which will print the tree key in ascending order . simultaneously keep comparing the key and print the first key that is greater than your key .. The time complexity will be less than O(n)

Comment: I have done it in in order traversal. But I cannot figure out how to retrieve the first value larger than key. If you look at the code I have one if statement to check if the key exists in the tree. But I cant figure out the else if statement which retrieves the first value larger than the key.

Comment: Integer x = null;
public Integer findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(BSTNode t, int key) { 
    // the scan terminates on an empty subtree
    if (t != null && x!=null) {


        // descend left 
        findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.left, key); 
        // visit the node
       

         if (t.nodeValue > key && found ||t.nodeValue==key){
            x = t.nodeValue;

        }
        // descend right
        findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.right, key);
        return x;
    } 

    return null;
}

//print X

Answer (score 0):

You can directly return the answer when you find it, since x is globally declared.

Your function should be something like this :

```
boolean found = false;
int x = 0;
public Integer findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(BSTNode t, int key) { 
    // the scan terminates on an empty subtree
    if (t != null) {


        // descend left 
        findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.left, key); 
        // visit the node
        if (t.nodeValue == key){
            found = true;
        }

        else if (t.nodeValue > key && found == true){
            x = t.nodeValue;
            return x;
        }
        // descend right
        findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.right, key);
        return x;
    } 

    return null;
}
```

Or, do something like this :

```
int x = 0;
public Integer findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(BSTNode t, int key) { 
    // the scan terminates on an empty subtree
    if (t != null) {


        // descend left 
        findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.left, key); 
        // visit the node
        if (t.nodeValue > key){
            x = t.nodevalue;
            return x;
        }
        // descend right
        findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.right, key);
        return x;
    } 

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try this out


    public Integer findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(BSTNode t, int key) { 
Integer x =null;
        // the scan terminates on an empty subtree
        if (t != null && x!=null) {


            // descend left 
            findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.left, key); 
            // visit the node


             if (t.nodeValue > key  ||t.nodeValue==key){
                x = t.nodeValue;


            }
            // descend right
            findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(t.right, key);

        } 

        return x;
    }
```

Comment: I having problems calling the method. I have created a binary tree and i am using `Integer s = bst.findFirstEntryLargerThanKey(null, key);` to call the method which gives me the result "null" every time. Can you plz help me fix this

Answer (score 0):

Lets try the usual key search with two extra steps:

```
 * Whenever we go left from a parent to a child, 
   remember the parent as a potential answer.
 * If the key is found and it has a right subtree, 
   then the answer is left-most (smallest) node of that subtree.

FindFirstEntryLargerThanKey(BSTNode t, int key) {
  BSTNode result_so_far = null;
  for (BSTNode cur = t; cur; ) {
    if (key < cur->key) {
      result_so_far = cur;
      cur = cur->left;
    }
    else if (key == cur->key) {
      if (cur->right) {
        result_so_far = LeftMostNode(cur->right);
      }
      break;
    }
    else {
      cur = cur->right;
    }
  }
  return result_so_far;
}
```